# R Get Count of Unique Column Values with Same but Lesser Other Column Values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R with student IDs and questionIDs from a test.  Students answer the questions sequentially but do not have to answer each question.  For each student and question, what I'm trying to get is a count of how many unique students answered earlier questions (with questID< the current questID) as this student.  Here is an example of the dataframe with some expected counts.  As an example, studentID 1 on questID 3 has answered 2 previous questions (1 and 2) and there was two other unique students (studentID 2 and 3) who answered these questions.  Any ideas how I can get these counts in R?
[image]

**data**

```
DF <- data.frame(studentID = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2,3), rep(3, 2)),
                 questID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1 , 2, 4, 2, 5))
```

Comment: Please provide your data using `dput()`.

Comment: I am confused as to what, exactly, you are looking for. Perhaps an example of what a desired result would look like would be helpful.

Comment: actually, the count column is what I'm looking for - I simply showed the count as example of the output...thanks

Comment: I am still not clear about the expected output shown. For student ID 1 and question ID 3, studentID 1 has answered two questions previously (ok till here) but student ID 3 never answered question 1 .Also what about last entry in question 5 for student 3. How is it 2 when nobody has answered question 5. Not clear how `count` is calculated.

Comment: Thanks..ok..if you look at student 3 who has answered question 5, but before they answered question 5 they answered question 2.  Now 2 other students (students ID of 1 and 2) have also answered question 2.  So, the key is not getting how many students are answering the current question (which is 5), but earlier questions the that student has answered.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Again, for student ID 1 question id 3 there are two previous question 1 & 2 which was answered only by student id 2 (not by 3) , Id 3 answered only question 2. If we have to consider any one of the previous questions then how for studentId 2 question 4, the previous questions are 1 & 2 but the count is only 1?

Comment: right....so for student ID 1 and question id 3, that student (ID 1) had previously answered question ID 1 and 2. Now, how many unique other students answered either question 1 or question 2.  Student 2 answered both  and student 3 answered question 2.  So, you have 2 unique students who answered previous questions.

Comment: and what about student id 2 and question id 4 ?

Comment: ah...that should be a count of 2 (not 1)...sorry about that.

Comment: and similarly the count should be 1 for student Id 1 , question id 2

Comment: Yes. You are right. Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crude-approach would be to create a function which counts the distinct number of `studentID` for values of `questID`.

```
library(dplyr)

get_counts <- function(x) {
    DF %>%
     group_by(studentID) %>%
     filter(any(questID %in% x)) %>%
     pull(studentID) %>% n_distinct - 1
}
```

Now we can `group_by` `studentID` and pass `questID` to `get_counts` function in an incremental fashion to get `count`. We change `count` to 0 for 1st `questID` in each group since it does not have any previous `questID` to check for.

```
DF %>%
  group_by(studentID) %>%
  mutate(count = purrr::map_dbl(row_number(), ~get_counts(questID[1:(.x - 1)])), 
         count = replace(count, 1, 0))

#  studentID questID count
#      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#1         1       1     0
#2         1       2     1
#3         1       3     2
#4         1       4     2
#5         2       1     0
#6         2       2     1
#7         2       4     2
#8         3       2     0
#9         3       5     2
```

Comment: Ok. Let me give that a try